# Слайд двух страничек

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть две страницы( enter.html  - вход на сайт и index.html- главная страница). На странице enter   по середине логотип. Хочу сделать что бы при нажатии на логотип страница enter.html  слайдом уезжало вверх а index.html появлялось слайдом снизу. Как можно такое реализовать.  Заранее спасибо! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<style>
#content {
    height: 20%;
    margin:10em;
    position: relative;
  left:20%;
    width: 20%;
  background:#f0f;
}
#fake_content{
  height:100%;width:100%;
}
#holder {
overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="holder">
    <div id="fake_content"></div>
    <div id="content">1312312<br>12312323</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    $("#fake_content").slideUp();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**enter.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<style>
#content {
    height: 20%;
    margin:10em;
    position: relative;
  left:20%;
    width: 20%;
  background:#f0f;
}
#fake_content{
  height:100%;width:100%;
}
#holder {
overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="holder">
    <div id="fake_content"></div>
    <div id="content">1312312<br>12312323</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    $("#fake_content").slideUp();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Кладите контент enter.html в div, по входу грузите страницу index.html через ajax, кладите её в див, сделайте анимацию смены дивов.

Что надо почитать из документации **jquery**:

1. [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
2. [$.slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)
3. [$.slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)
4. [$.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)